# Is there a way to get all the previous version of a deleted s3 object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket with versioning enabled. I have implemented rename functionality. For that first I am copying the object and then deleting the old one(Not permanently, only marked as deleted) as there is no direct method to rename a file in S3.

For e.g: We have an object as 'logo.jpg' that has multiple versions. Now I have renamed it as 'logo1.jpg'. After renaming, I am able to fetch version of 'logo1.jpg' but how to fetch all versions of 'logo.jpg' that has been deleted(Not permanently, marked as deleted in S3).

To fetch all version, using below code

```
   ListVersionsRequest request = new ListVersionsRequest()
                    .withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(
                            key);

            VersionListing versionListing = s3.listVersions(request);
            for (S3VersionSummary obj2 : versionListing
                    .getVersionSummaries()) {
               obj2.getKey();
               obj2.getVersionId();
            }
```

It is working when fetching the key and version for 'logo1.jpg'.
But when trying the same for 'logo.jpg'(deleted object), getting exception as:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception with Error Code: 405

I am not able to fetch version and key of a deleted object in S3.

Comment: You need to explain what the problem is with the code you have shown.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod, I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you are receiving? Are you listing the versions of `logo.jpg`? It is failing on `.getVersionSummaries()`?